# precisely slice a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, numpy-slicing

I want to slice a 3D array

> [-500:500]

to subarrays in sequence 100 subarrays of length 2 then one of length 50 then 100 of length 2 then one of length 50, and I wish every subarray is spaced by length one from the following.

Comment: Better add a toy example of the expected output

Comment: x = np.linspace(-500, 500,2)
# I want to exclude 'x' from the array, then slice the rest to 100 and 100.
# Note: I need to control steps 'size of array', and I need a space between resulted arrays, and all these arrays are 3D "volumes"

Answer (score 1):

This solution is the only one that worked for me:
The purpose of the slicing is to distribute particles inside the box.
I used software called `gsd` to produce a GSD file.

*) get the `xyz` file, with the help of another software (I used jmol program ), then you have the orientations of the particles in the model.
I wrote the orientations into my program to avoid overlapping.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).